# Resque on Heroku cedar stack Worker count still exists after the worker terminate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redis, resque

I have successfully run resque on heroku cedar stack and mount the interface on rails.

when I start the worker, Everything works fine. The worker process the job. But When i kill the worker, Resque still think that the worker is available. When I start another worker, it then think there are 2 worker but in fact there is only one running.

I also notice form here http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps that heroku send SIGTERM when killing a worker and if that does not terminate then it send SIGKILL.

here is my worker logs

```
2011-08-11T02:32:45+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*`
2011-08-11T02:32:46+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-08-11T02:33:58+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to stopping
2011-08-11T02:34:00+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-08-11T02:34:09+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> Process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2011-08-11T02:34:09+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2011-08-11T02:34:11+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited
```

I see that my process takes more then 10s to terminate. Is this have anything to do because I load up rails environment on the worker task ?

this is my rake task `lib/tasks/resque.rake`

```
require "resque/tasks"

task "resque:setup"  => :environment
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found out the problem, this happend when passing `ENV` on the rake task. like when passing `QUEUE='*'`.

Here is the issue more complete
https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/319#issuecomment-1789239

and the issue are still in discus at https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/368

any my temporary patch, that make resque only run all que.

https://github.com/yulrizka/resque

Comment: you can also clean up from console by connecting to redis and running .del('workers')

Answer (score 2):

ahmy,

Based on your solution, I came up with one that doesn't involve forking resque.

I put this in `resque.rake`:

```
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end
```

and put this in the `Profile`:

```
worker:  bundle exec rake resque:work
```

and put this in the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'resque', :git => 'git://github.com/defunkt/resque.git'
```